# SQL Updating entire column based on Primary key from another table

Tags: mysql, sql

Example we have 2 tables:

device_tb has columns "device_num" and "device_name"

property_tb has columns "id" and "item_name(currently null or placeholder values)"

device_tb.device_num is equal to the property_tb.id as in it lists the unique id of the product.

If i want to update property_tb.item_name with the strings from device_name instead of manually keying in the names how would i go about it?

Would this work?

```
UPDATE property_tb 
SET item_name= device_tb.device_name
WHERE property_tb.id = device_tb.device_num
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to join both the tables before updating. Here is the sample code

```
UPDATE property_tb 
SET property_tb.item_name = device_tb.device_name
FROM property_tb 
JOIN device_tb ON property_tb.id = device_tb.device_num
```

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, the correct syntax for an `UPDATE` with `JOIN` is:

```
UPDATE property_tb p JOIN
       device_tb d
       ON p.id = d.device_num
    SET p.item_name= d.device_name;
```